# python re backreference repeated elements

Tags: python, regex, backreference

Let's say I have a string like this...

```
myStr = 'START1(stuff); II(morestuff); 8(lessstuff)'
```

...and I want to extract the string immediately before the parentheses, as well as the string within the parentheses: `1`, `stuff`, `II`, `morestuff`, `8`, `lessstuff`.  I can achieve this using `split(';')`, etc., but I want to see if I can do it in one fell swoop with `re.search()`. I have tried...

```
test = re.search( r'START(?:([I0-9]+)\(([^)]+?)\)(?:; )?)*', myStr ).groups()
```

...or in a more readable format...

```
test = re.search( r'''
                  START         # This part begins each string
                  (?:           # non-capturing group
                    ([I0-9]+)   # capture label before parentheses
                    \(
                      ([^)]+?)  # any characters between the parentheses
                    \)
                    (?:; )?     # semicolon + space delimiter
                  )*
                  ''', myStr, re.VERBOSE ).groups()
```

...but I only get the *last* hit: `('8', 'lessstuff')`. Is there a way to backreference multiple hits of the same part of the expression?

Comment: You want `START1` or just `1`?

Comment: If you're going to do that, it is imperative that you learn about the `re.VERBOSE` flag first: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE  ;-)

Comment: @heemayl Just `1`. I could have left `START` off for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex in `findall` to capture your text:

```
>>> myStr = 'START1(stuff); II(morestuff); 8(lessstuff)'
>>> print re.findall(r'(?:START)?(\w+)\(([^)]*)\)', myStr)
[('1', 'stuff'), ('II', 'morestuff'), ('8', 'lessstuff')]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jF6cO6/1)

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten about `findall()`!